# initialize error of ComboBox : Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

When I try to initialize the model of ComboBox, weird error pop out

test.pro

```
# Add more folders to ship with the application, here
folder_01.source = qml/androidTest
folder_01.target = qml
DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS = folder_01

#QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x
CONFIG   += c++11
QT += qml quick

# The .cpp file which was generated for your project. Feel free to hack it.
SOURCES += main.cpp

OTHER_FILES += \
    qml/androidTest/main.qml
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);   

    QQuickView view;
    view.setSource(QUrl("/Users/Qt/program/experiment_apps_and_libs/test/qml/test/main.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

main1.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

Rectangle {
width: 100
height: 62

ListModel{
id: modelA
}

ComboBox{
model: modelA
}

Component.onCompleted: {
modelA.append({"source" : "hhhh"})
}
}
```

error message

file:///C:/Qt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/mingw48_32/qml/QtQuick/Controls/ComboBox.qml:496: TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined

How could I fix this error?

Edit 1 :

I do not make an inline model because I want to separate the construction of the model and the ComboBox.It is hard to explain by my poor english, here is a simple example

TextCB

```
Column{
    id: root    

    function appendUnitModel(units){
        for(var i = 0; i != units.length; ++i){
            unitModel.append({"unit": units[i]});
        }
    }    

    property alias inputText: input.text

    SystemPalette{id: palette}    

    ListModel{
        id: unitModel
    }

    Row{
        spacing: 5

        Text{
            id: input

            color: palette.highlight
            height: root.height / 2
            width: root.width * 0.6
            focus: true
            font.family: "Helvetica"
            font.pixelSize: 16; font.bold: true

            //Behavior on height{ NumberAnimation{duration: 500} }

            MouseArea{
                anchors.fill: parent

                onClicked: {
                    showKeyBoard()
                }
            }
        }

        ComboBox{
            id: unitSelector

            model: unitModel
            editable: true
            height: input.height
            width: root.width - input.width
        }
    }    
}
```

main2.qml

```
 TextCB{
    id: inputAndClear

    height: root.height * 0.2
    width: root.width        

    Component.onCompleted: {
        var units = ["meters", "decimeters", "centimeters",
                     "millimeters", "kilometers", "inches",
                     "feet", "yards", "miles", "nautical miles",
                     "cables"]

        inputAndClear.appendUnitModel(units)
    }

}
```

Separate the construction of the model and ComboBox, I could reuse it more easier.

Edit 2 :
For those who do not use QtCreator, here is the command line

1. /Users/yyyy/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/clang_64/bin/qmake -makefile -d test.pro
2. make
3. cd androidTest.app/Contents/MacOS
4. lldb test
5. run

This commands are under OSX, you may need to tune it a little bit under different OS(ex : change lldb to gdb)

Comment: If you want to run the application, just open a new QtQuick project and paste the contents of main1.qml on your main.qml, it is all you need.Besides, I already post all of the error messages shown by the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to set the "source" property for the `ListElement` of the `ListModel` rather than 'text' what it expects. Respectively, if you change the following line:

```
modelA.append({"source" : "hhhh"})
```

to:

```
modelA.append({"text" : "hhhh"})
```

it will work. Alternatively, you could also add the following line to your ComboBox to get your custom role taking effect:

```
ComboBox {
    model: modelA
    textRole: "source"
}
```

See the ComboBox code for detailed explanation about it:

```
// No text role set, check whether model has a suitable role
// If 'text' is found, or there's only one role, pick that.
```

You also have other minor issues in your code, like hard coding the qml path for Windows as showed below. You could change to either "main.qml" simply, or use the resource system.

```
view.setSource(QUrl("/Users/Qt/program/experiment_apps_and_libs/test/qml/test/m‌​ain.qml"));
```

I personally changed it locally simply to:

```
view.setSource(QUrl("m‌​ain.qml"));
```

Also, you seem to have unnecessary qmake options for this experiment set up as follows:

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

and

```
QT += qml quick
```

For the latter, you do not need to specify `qml` explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, specify the textRole as "unit" do solve the problem.I find out using loader to load the ComboBox after insert the data into the ListModel also work(I try this solution because I find out that if you don't initialize the model in onCompleted block, the error will not issue).The absolute path is evil, thanks for your advice.